# undefined in React, its doesn't recognise the props - but why?

Tags: reactjs

I need to get the DishDetail component in the `DishDetailComponent.js` file to render the props passed to it from a specific item which has been clicked in the Menu component in the `MenuComponent.js`. Currently, my `renderComments()` syntax is crashing the load. If I take that out then it will load the page, and doesn't crash when i click on one of the displayed dishes but it doesn't do anything. When using the React tools, it tells me that DishDetail component has 2 props - dish and comments but it says they are undefined.

My problem is two fold (I think) - a) I haven't got the correct code for the `DishDetail` component to receive the props of the *selected* item.

and b) how I write the correct syntax for access the comments attribute of the dish item in order to show the comment about a particular dish.

`MenuComponent.js`

```
class Menu extends Component {

   constructor(props) {
       super(props);
        this.state = {
        selectedDish: null

        };
      }

    onDishSelect(dish){
       this.setState({selectedDish: dish});
   }

    render() {
      const menu = this.props.dishes.map((dish) => {
           return (
             <div key={dish.id} className="col-12 col-md-5 m-1">
              <Card onClick={() => this.onDishSelect(dish)}>
                  <CardImg width="100%" object src={dish.image} alt={dish.name} />
                  <CardImgOverlay>
                          <CardTitle>{dish.name}</CardTitle>
                  </CardImgOverlay>
              </Card>
             </div>
           );
        });

       return (
           <div className="container">
               <div className="row">
                   {menu}
               </div>
                   <DishDetail dish={this.state.dish} comments={this.state.comments}/>
           </div>
       );
    }
}

export default Menu;
```

`DishDetailComponent.js`

```
class DishDetail extends Component {
    constructor (props){
       super(props);
  }

 renderDish(dish) {
    if (dish != null){
        return (
            <div className="col-12 col-md-5 m-1">
               <Card>
                    <CardImg top src={this.props.dish.image} alt={this.props.dish.name} />
                    <CardBody>
                        <CardTitle>{this.props.dish.name}</CardTitle>
                        <CardText>{this.props.dish.description}</CardText>
                    </CardBody>
                </Card>  
            </div>
           )
    } else {
        return (
            <div>
            </div>
        )
    }  
 }

 renderComments(dish)  {
   const comment = this.props.comments.map((comments) => {
             return (
            <div className="col-12 col-md-5 m-1">
                    <p>{this.props.comment.comment}</p>
                    <p>{this.props.comment.author}</p>
                    <p>{this.props.comment.date}</p>
            </div>
            )
         })

    }
```

Comment: There's no render inside `DishDetail`.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like there are a couple of things to fix.

First. The `DishDetail` component needs a `render()` method which can read the properties passed as input.

Second. In  `MenuComponent` the `state` is either `null` or it contains `{selectedDish: dish}`. Therefore you may try to access `this.state.selectedDish`, but not `this.state.dish` or `this.state.comment`.

You may want to use something like `console.log(state)` inside the `render()` function so you can see in the console what is in your state and which values you are passing as props to other components.

Hope it helps.
Ciao.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help. looks like ive not cut and pasted properly as i missed off the render function in the dishDetail component...                                                       
  render(){
         return (
            <div className="row">
             {this.renderDish(this.props.selectedDish)}
             {this.renderComments(this.props.selectedDish)} 
            </div>   
        )  
             
    }
}


export default DishDetail;

Comment: so still im still not sure how i fix this, I've tried changing to this.state.selectedDish but that didn't change it.